# Web Scraping in Google Scholar

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, google-scholar

I'm trying to scrape from Google Scholar profile pages.The idea is that I want to retrieve the publications' list with an XPath but I does not download the page, here's my code:
I tried with curl

```
function get_page($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
//I tried to change user agent as well
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;  en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
}
```

And without curl :

```
function get_xpath($query_url) {
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($query_url);
sleep(1);
return new DOMXpath($dom);
}

$query_url = "https://scholar.google.it/citations?user=p-POZjgAAAAJ&hl=it&cstart=0&pagesize=100";
```

To get it without curl

```
$xpath = get_xpath($query_url);
```

To get it with curl

```
$xpath = get_xpath(get_page($query_url));
```

And then

```
$autori=$xpath->query("//tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]");
```

But $autori keeps being empty, any idea?

Comment: You can test your xpath queries using browser addons like https://addons.mozilla.org/En-uS/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/ . Check if your xpath works or not , then you can find what is your problem xpath or curl.

Comment: never **EVER** use `@`. it's the php equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you". plus, you're simply assuming that your scrape is actually succeeding. done any basic debugging, like checking if the url can be scraped at all? `echo file_get_contents($query_url)`? checked that you're getting the page you THINK you're supposed to get?

Comment: The xpath works, I already checked it, thanks. @ElvinValiev

Comment: @MarcB of coure I tried, as I said i cannot download the page, with file_get_contents it keeps giving me a Server Error, I supposed it could be scraped because I scraped on another google scholar page (not a profile one though...)

Comment: And i suppressed the error because it keeps getting me this error "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : table in https://scholar.google.it/citations?user=TSpglVcAAAAJ, line: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\GAD\numberOfCommonPapers.php on line 19"

Comment: Then take it as a sign that scraping isn't really permitted: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/api-eula-and-scraping-for-google-scholar